# How to solve Problem with date format in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have problem with date format in the chinese language I want to show weekday day month but getting the output as month day weekday below is the code I am using

```
 _iconDateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale;
 [_iconDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE d MMMM"];
 [_iconDateFormatter setDateFormat:[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEEE d MMMM" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];
  iconText = [_iconDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
 NSLog(@"%@",iconText);
```

the output of icon text

```
4月23日 周二
```

but what I want is like this `周二 23日4月`

Any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `dateFormatFromTemplate` to generate your format. This does *not* give you the exact format that you specify; it *changes* the format in response to the localized settings on the device.

If you want complete control over the format, just set the `dateFormat` with an explicit format directly.